# error : actuatorTorque // setInitPose

Tags: ros-kinetic, rviz, ubuntu, dynamixel, realsense

Our team is following [this manual](https://github.com/minwoominwoominwoo7/open_manipulator_find_object_2d.git), and we have run into an error when attempting to call the `/set_actuator_state` and `/goal_joint_space_path` services.

This is the detail:

1. We [installed open manipulator](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator_x/ros_setup/#install-ros-packages)
2. Then we installed [the realsense code](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator_x/ros_applications/#installation-1)
3. And the [open manipulator camera application](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator_x/ros_applications/#install-ar-marker-package) to identify AR markers
4. We also installed `find_object_2d`:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-find-object-2d
sudo apt-get install python-pyside
```

5. After building, we run the launch files:
   https://github.com/minwoominwoominwoo7/open_manipulator_find_object_2d

```
roscore
roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_rgbd.launch
roslaunch open_manipulator_controller open_manipulator_controller.launch
roslaunch open_manipulator_find_object_2d object_detection.launch
roslaunch open_manipulator_find_object_2d tracking.launch
```

But we got error messages for last step:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.17
 * /tracking/use_platform: True

NODES
  /
    tracking (open_manipulator_find_object_2d/tracking)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[tracking-1]: started with pid [21311]
[INFO] [1694778337.203501]: tracking_controller
[WARN] [1694778338.234782]: actuatorTorque
Service call failed: service [/set_actuator_state] unavailable
[WARN] [1694778338.236181]: setInitPose
Service call failed: service [/goal_joint_space_path] unavailable
[INFO] [1694778338.237230]: init mode
[WARN] [1694778338.237613]: setInitPose
Service call failed: service [/goal_joint_space_path] unavailable
```

How can we move our robot arm? We're using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.